# SQL- Count the age count from 1 table and put it in a column as per date range of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is 1 table T1. as per below image

[image]

And 2nd Table T2

[image]

Now I have to use T1 as source table and put the counts in 'no of member' as per the Age of T2

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your sql code, the value of T2.age has to be split, i choose [SQL substring](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/substring.php)
Here's your SQL, i did not test it but it should work, if I find a mistake i'll edit:

```
Update T2 set no_of_member = 
    (Select COUNT(*) FROM T1 
        WHERE T1.age 
        BETWEEN substring(T2.age,1,instr(T2.age,"-") -1) AND           ´
                substring(T2.age,instr(T2.age,"-"),LEN(T2.age))
    );
```

---

Explanation:

`substring(T2.age,1,instr(T2.age,"-") -1)`

gets the value of the first age in T2.age, by using the initial position of the string and the position of the `"-"` character for example

`T2.age = '23-25'` ---> `substring(T2.age,1,instr(T2.age,"-") -1) = 23`

The same goes for
`substring(T2.age,instr(T2.age,"-"),LEN(T2.age) = 25`

The rest is simple update query

---

**Advice**:
Don't save T2.age like that (`"23-25"`). Rather separate it so that you can run simpler and faster queries, by having one column `T2.from` and another `T2.until`, or something like that

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is a correlated subquery.  However, the structure of `t2` is bad.  You should have columns with the minimum and maximum values.  Because you don't have this, your query is more complicated than it really needs to be:

```
update t2
    set numOfMembers = (select count(*)
                        from t1
                        where t1.age >= substring_index(t2.age, '-', 1) + 0 and
                              t2.age <= substring_index(t2.age, '-', -1) + 0
                       );
```

Don't put two values in a single column (such as your range).  Instead, have two columns, `minage` and `maxage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from t1, t2 where t1.Age between LEFT(t2.age , 2) and Right(t2.age , 2) group by t2.age
```

this will gives u your desire no of member count

Comment: You are assuming the lenth of the age is always two, it would neither work for 9-12 nor for 98-101. plus you are creating a new table, not updating T2.